# update 1to many many child record when parent is updated

Tags: mysql

I have a parent table "DROP" with a compound key that is unique

the child table "DROP_MATERIAL" can have 0-many records with the same compound key as a foreign
key with a primary key that is generated and never used

If a DROP column is updated I want to update each of the related child records

Any one have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Look at trigger https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: I can create an after update  trigger for the "DROP" table to access the "DROP_MATERIAL" table but what I need to do is read each of the child records and update them

Comment: do I just do an UPDATE DROP_MATERIAL